# How to allow uploading only CSV and XLS files?

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to restrict my code so that when I upload a file, the file extension can only be xls and csv.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") 
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") 
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") 
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") 
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") 
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) 
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) 
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Comment: Post you code here plz.

Comment: The code you've linked is pretty generic (found in a myriad of places on the interweb) about validating uploads based on image extensions and mime types; how difficult is it to change that so it at least looks as though you've tried to make it for xls and csv?

Comment: i understand that, but i want to learn also, and like this is pretty easy to me

Comment: These are the different [MIME types](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list); use this to determine the `$_FILES['file']['type']` to match against.

Comment: done
it looks like this :<link> http://pastebin.com/iaEZH91B </link> 
now all i have to do is make the output file be named by date with " - " between. some  ideeas?